# Halacha super book?

Tags: halacha, shulchan-aruch

Is there a book of Halacha that presents the Rif, Rambam, and Rosh alongside the conclusions of the Shulchan Aruch for each Halacha?
If not, maybe someone should make one.

Comment: I would argue that you just described טור with בית יוסף

Comment: Tzurbah M'Rabanan ...not all topics

Comment: Are you asking in Hebrew or English?